# Why would Mysql's Round(N.DD,1) sometimes show no digits after the decimal place when using the Perl DBI?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, perl

We have a set of calculations that do something like

SELECT ROUND(SUM(ROUND(3*IP))/3,1) as IP_sum from ....

Say for example that IP_sum is exactly 180.

When we call from the mysql client we get 180.0 every time, but if we use the perl dbi, the result depends on IP's column type.

When IP is a decimal(7,1) we get one digit and IP_sum => '180.0'
When IP is a float(7,1) we don't get any digits => IP_sum => '180'

Is anyone aware of a new change or update to the Perl DBI that might be causing this?  We just updated some modules and programs this week.

Engine: Mysql 5.6,  mysql client, 5.5.

Comment: If you are talking about the  _mysql_ datatype `FLOAT(7,1)`, well do _not_ use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT`.  Use either `DECIMAL(7,1)` or plain `FLOAT` in MySQL.

Comment: Rick James, it still seems like a strange behavior when calling ROUnD(num,1) on the column

Comment: Please elaborate on "strange".

Comment: seems to me that "SELECT ROUND(example,3) from foo" should return ?.XXX regardless of the type of column example is.  Maybe that's against the spec.  I'm not sure.

Comment: My comment was not a real answer -- it was talking about `FLOAT`.  HVS has the "real answer".

Comment: I know he works with me and we sorted it out.  You asked me why it was strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was unrelated to MySQL and was due to a change in the Perl DBD::mysql packages from version 4.013 to 4.042. Essentially, DBD::mysql now attempts to coerce the MySQL datatype into a Perl datatype. So, previously, a float of 4.0 would be returned as a string '4.0', but now the same float will be returned as a numeric value and be displayed as '4' when printed (without additional formatting on the part of Perl.

Comment: excellent answer.  I'm sure this took a great deal of work to track down.